Invariance under $\operatorname{Aut}(N / \{M\})$
Let $M\preceq N$ where $N$ is $|M|^+$ saturated.
Let $p(x)$ be a partial type over $\le|M|$ parameters.
What do we know (if anything at all) about when $p(N)$ is invariant under the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(N/\{M\})$, i.e. the automorphisms of $N$ that fix $M$ setwise?
(For a comparison: if $p(N)$ is invariant under $\operatorname{Aut}(N/M)$ then $p(x)$ is equivalent to a type over $M$.)

Every type which is invariant under automorphisms which fix $M$ setwise is in particular invariant under automorphisms which fix $M$ pointwise, right? So any such type is also equivalent to a type over $M$...

Well, the question is, ... what do we know more ?

For instance (if I am not mistaken) under the assumption of stability (and maybe some saturation of $M$) one can infer that $p(x)$ is definable over acl$^{\rm eq}(\varnothing)$. What about the general case?

First of all, I think you really want to assume that $N$ is $|M|^+$-strongly homogeneous as well as $|M|^+$-saturated. If $N$ fails to be sufficiently strongly homogeneous, the automorphism group of $N$ may not tell you very much (see below for more on this). For example, to prove

If $p(N)$ is invariant under $\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}\Aut(N/M)$, then $p(x)$ is equivalent to a type over $M$.

... you need $N$ to be $|M|^+$-strongly homogeneous as well as $|M|^+$-saturated. For example, if $N$ is actually a saturated model of cardinality greater than $|M|$, then it satisfies these hypotheses.
Ok, so let's assume $M\preceq N$, $N$ is $|M|^+$-saturated and $|M|^+$-strongly homogeneous, and $p(x)$ is a partial type over $B$ which is $\Aut(N/\{M\})$-invariant, where $B\subseteq N$ and $|B|\leq |M|$.
Since $p(x)$ is in particular $\Aut(N/M)$-invariant, it is equivalent to a partial type over $M$. So we may assume $B = M$.
Now since $N$ is $|M|^+$-strongly homogeneous, every automorphism $\sigma\in \Aut(M)$ extends to an automorphism $\sigma'\in \Aut(N)$. Since $\sigma'$  fixes $M$ setwise, it fixes $p(N)$ and therefore (since $N$ realizes all complete types over $M$), it fixes $p$ as a closed subset of $S(M)$. So, as a partial type over $M$, $p(x)$ is $\Aut(M)$-invariant.
At this point, what we can say really depends on properties of $M$.
At one extreme, if $M$ is rigid, every partial type over $M$ is $\Aut(M)$-invariant (and there is no difference between $\Aut(N/M)$-invariance and $\Aut(N/\{M\})$-invariance).
At the other extreme, if $M$ is itself sufficiently saturated and strongly homogeneous, then we can view $M$ as a "monster model" and $p$ as a "global" (partial) $\varnothing$-invariant type.
A lot is known about global invariant types in various settings. For example, such a type never divides over $\varnothing$ (and if it is complete, it never forks). Hence, as you said in the comments, if we assume stability, a complete global type invariant over $\varnothing$ is definable over $\mathrm{acl}^\mathrm{eq}(\varnothing)$.

A bit more on $\kappa$-saturated models which fail to be $\kappa$-strongly homogeneous.
It apparently follows from work of Shelah that it is consistent with ZFC that there is a rigid $\aleph_1$-saturated structure. The idea is to take an ultraproduct of the finite fields $\mathbb{F}_p$ (which are individually rigid) by a carefully selected non-principal ultrafilter on the set of primes. Every ultraproduct by a non-principal ultrafilter on a countable set is $\aleph_1$-saturated, but Shelah shows that the rigidity can be transferred up from the factors to the ultraproduct under certain conditions.
I say "apparently" because I haven't read the proofs, and the theorem is not stated in this form in Shelah's paper. The relevant paper is Vive la différence III. The quotable consequence about rigid ultraproducts is Theorem 1.2 in Automorphism Groups of Ultraproducts of Finite Symmetric Groups by Lücke and Thomas.
Now if $N$ is a rigid $\aleph_1$-saturated model and $M$ is a countable elementary substructure, then $\Aut(N/\{M\})$ is trivial, so every partial type is $\Aut(N/\{M\})$-invariant, and we can say nothing at all about such types.
